# Java threads termination

Tags: java, multithreading

I have several threads in an array.
All the threads are operating on a LinkedBlockingQueue.
Each thread takes an element (which is a file name) from the queue, reads it's dependencies (simple I/O) and adds those dependencies to the queue so we can get their dependencies as well. At some point, the queue will be empty (when we have discovered all dependencies). The questions is, how do I check if all threads are waiting for an element from the queue and if so, how do I terminate them?
I "hacked" it to work by using the method poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) but I want to terminate them from the main method.

EDIT:
I can't terminate on the condition that the queue is empty because at first we might have only one file in the queue and while a thread is processing it, the queue is empty for a while, until new dependencies are discovered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us some code, please. Don't understand why a thread can't detect that the queue is empty and then terminates?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea: Have an atomic integer count the number of threads that are "out of work". Once main notices that this counter reaches the length of the array N, have it put N special elements into the queue that, when obtained by a thread, cause it to end.

Comment: Nice idea, but instead of tying up a thread just waiting for the end of the crawl, why not have the last worker to enter the out-of-work state send the shutdown signal?